# What can change the default order of an Active Record relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-activerecord

I have a small Rails 4 project on Heroku. In the view there's a table whose contents are displayed using `Model.all.each.` Every so often -- I think it's whenever the model gets updated -- the ordering of the table changes. Disturbingly, I haven't been able to reproduce this quirk on localhost. Although it's easy enough to correct, I'm concerned it might a symptom of some other, undiscovered problem.

[EDIT: The behavior only arises during iteration. If I index into the collection, it returns the expected element]

[SECOND EDIT: Scratch the first edit. I had assumed that `Model.first` was equivalent to `Model.all[0],` but running the console from Heroku has shown me that it clearly isn't: The first gives me the record with id 1, the second gives me the record with id 10 (the one that appears first when I run `each`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you aren't using postgres in development, but are doing so on Heroku because that's the default?

From postgres' docs:

> If sorting is not chosen, the rows will be returned in an unspecified
>   order. The actual order in that case will depend on the scan and join
>   plan types and the order on disk, but it must not be relied on.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-order.html

Comment: When you update a row in PostgreSQL, it moves it. If you start by inserting 10 rows and then select all of them they're likely to come back in the order they were inserted: 1,2,3,... 10. If you update row 2 then the order is likely to become 1,3,4,... 10,2. Never rely on a sort order unless you have applied it yourself.

Comment: @DavidAldridge That's it! When I did a test update I didn't notice the record had been moved to the end because I checked it with Model.last instead of Model.all[-1]. If you'll post this as an answer I'll give you credit.